# MySQL check if row exists, insert if FALSE, loop if TRUE

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a very simple bit of PHP that generates a random string and echos it to the user. In order to avoid duplication, I want to insert these values into a MySQL table. Each time the user generates a new string, I need to check if it exists in the table, if it does not then I can insert the value, but if it does then I need to loop the random generation to get another value, perform the same check and insert that into the table.

I am an absolute beginner, but have been searching for hours and getting nowhere.

In pseudo code, I'd like it to do something like this, where $VAL is my random variable and UniqueNo is my table:

```
$val=substr(md5(rand()),-5)
IF NOT EXISTS($val IN UniqueNo)
THEN INSERT INTO UniqueNo (ID) VALUES ('$val')
ELSE
GOTO Line 1
END
```

Comment: I suggest you look for a guaranteed-unique generator API or method.  This approach doesn't scale well; you'll run out of entropy eventually and at that point your method will hang indefinitely.

Comment: http://www.guidgenerator.com/online-guid-generator.aspx

Comment: Try http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php

Comment: I have considered uniqid, but I need something more user friendly than a full 13 character string as projects will be referenced with these values. I have no issues with there being enough entropy. The issue is a) how to structure the 'IF' for the insert and b) how to loop back to generating the If if a duplicate is found. Count/Insert Ignore etc do not help in this case.

Answer (score 0):

PHP pseudo code for this:

```
$val=substr(md5(rand()),-5);
select columnname from table where UniqueNo=$val;
if return 0 THEN INSERT INTO UniqueNo (ID) VALUES ('$val')
```

Comment: Something like this? It's still not quite right, but the columnname is returning a 0 if ($return="0") {
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO UniqueNo (ID) VALUES ('$val')");
echo $val;
}

Comment: $con = mysqli_connect("example.com","peter","abc123","my_db");
mysql_select_db("database", $link);

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM tableWithUnickString WHERE unickString='$unickString'");
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
if ($num_rows==0) {
$unickString='ganereteitsomehow';
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM tableWithUnickString WHERE unickString='$unickString'");
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
if ($num_rows==0) {
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO tableWithUnickString (unickString) VALUES ('$unickString');
}
}

Comment: you can add while loop here but when you will run out of uniqe string it will loop continuously